# Do you know to find the sum of the series?

Tags: functions

I need to find the sum of the series $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}$$

Comment: you mean the partial sum. Do rationalization of denominator and simplify. Do for example a sum of first 10 terms.

Answer (score 3):

As
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}} = \frac{-\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}}{(k+1) - (k)} 
= -\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}
$$
you have $$
\sum_{k = 1}^N  \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^N -\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1} =
-1 + \sqrt{N+1} \to \infty
$$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac1{\sqrt k+\sqrt{k+1}}\ge\frac1{2\sqrt{k+1}}$$

thus (why?) the series diverges: it has no sum.